# Problematic delete with SQL index

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-update

I have some table:

- table ASK with `idask`
- table PREFERENCES with `idpref`, `fk_idask`, `fk_idstructure`
- table STRUCTURE with `idstructure`

With all the constraint between the `id` and the `fk_id` and a unique index on the table PREFERENCES (`fk_idask`, `fk_idstructure`).

The problem is when I have two row in PREFERENCES.

```
`IDPREF`   `FK_IDASK`   `FK_IDSTRUCTURE`  
 1          1            1  
 2          1            2
```

If I want to invert(switch?) the two structure between the preferences

```
`IDPREF`   `FK_IDASK`   `FK_IDSTRUCTURE`  
 1          1            **2**
 2          1            **1**
```

The unique index between `FK_IDASK` and `FK_IDSTRUCTURE` break up, because with the first update result in two preferences for the same ask with the same structure.

For prevent this, I make a function deleteAndResave and this solve the problem for the moment.

But now the arrive the  ASSIGNATION table with `idassignation` and `fk_idpref`.

Now if I delete a Preference linked by an ASSIGNATION the constraint break.

I already find a workaround, but is ugly. There is some sane solution for this problem?

Thanks for the answer!

ps. Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE
    PREFERENCES
SET
    FK_IDSTRUCTURE = 3 - FK_IDSTRUCTURE
```

Now, because it runs in one go, the "C" (Consistency) in "ACID" means that foreign keys and uniqueness are handled "during" but will be OK before and after.

You can pimp the statement with CASE statements for more complex stuff

```
UPDATE
    PREFERENCES
SET
    FK_IDSTRUCTURE = CASE FK_IDSTRUCTURE 
        WHEN 2 THEN 1 WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE FK_IDSTRUCTURE END
```

Comment: the first one work only for the swap case. (in my real word case, a user can chose the structure and can accidentaly swap structure, but it's not the rule).

By the way the second example a little generalizated can work... tomorrow i give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

Yah, inverted two structures between table index and break up!

Anyway, I'm guessing your foreign key is pointing the wrong way.  It looks like the foreign key is on assignation, and pointing to preferences.

The foreign key should be on preferences, and REFERENCE assignation.

Another option is to consider an ON DELETE CASCADE option on the foreign key.  This means that when you delete rows in the referenced table, the database engine automatically deletes the relevant rows in the foreign key table.

Another often used option is to keep the rows, but mark them as inactive. This can be done by adding an "active bit" column.  When querying you filter out the rows marked as inactive.

Comment: the assignation can not be deleted if i change a preferences.

About the preferences pointing to the assignation...yes this solve the problem. But on the other side, if i delete an assignation i need to delete the foreing key on the preferences(this result in one update to null and a delete). I not like it very much